# how to call public void in protected void

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have this code which I want to call in Button1_click pls help me.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
public static void RestartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds) 
{
    ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName); 
    try { int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount; 
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);
    service.Stop();      
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout); 
    // count the rest of the timeout 
    int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
    timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2-millisec1)); 
    service.Start(); service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
}
catch {  } 
}
```

Comment: you need 2 values `serviceName` and `timeoutMilliseconds`

Comment: basically @fubo is trying to tell you, you can call it this way: `RestartService("somestring", 999);`. assuming both method in the same class. although i wonder why is there a `catch` there (at the end of the code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call the Method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RestartService("serviceName", 3000);
}
```

You have to fill the parameter serviceName and Timeout with your values for sure.